# label boxplot with jitters

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, label

Hi I am trying to create a boxplot with the following code. However it's not taking the labels. Would appreciate any thoughts and help;

```
ggplot(fcast_data1, aes(x=weekday, y=mape_ExpExpFcstShort, labels("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + #avoid plotting outliers twice
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0)) + mytheme + ggtitle("May Forecast in May")
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with the `label` function here.... Your question provides no information about what you are trying to do or why it is going wrong, nor is it reproducible.

Comment: do you mean to have `labels = c("Sunday", ...)`

Comment: Please provide reproducible data, e.g. paste the output of 'dput(fcast_data1)' so that we can actually run your code.

Comment: My data looks something like this. I am trying to create a boxplot for the  weekday for the variables mape_MultExpSmoothFcst; pe_MultExpSmoothFcst
So I will have 7 boxplot candles 1 for each weekday. However, somehow I am unable to get the x axis labels as weekday names with my code. Below is a sample of the data. date mape_MultExpSmoothFcst pe_MultExpSmoothFcst weekday
5/1/2017 39.89361702 39.89361702 2
5/1/2017 59.00277008 59.00277008 2
5/1/2017 42.31678487 42.31678487 1
5/1/2017 32.20720721 32.20720721 1
5/1/2017 36.9047619 36.9047619 3
5/1/2017 26.4033264 26.4033264 3

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood OP's intentions correctly he wants

- to plot some y values versus `weekday` (given as numeric or integer
  in his data) on the x-axis and
- to label the x-axis with the names of the days rather than the number.

To achieve this, I suggest to convert the weekdays to factor labelling the factor levels appropriately:

```
fcast_data1$weekday <- factor(fcast_data1$weekday, 
                              levels = 1:7,
                              labels = c(
                                "Sunday",
                                "Monday",
                                "Tuesday",
                                "Wednesday",
                                "Thursday",
                                "Friday",
                                "Saturday"))
```

Note that two assumptions are made here:

1. In the OP's data, `weekday` `1` means Sunday and
2. The week starts on a Sunday.

In other cases, either the levels and/or the labels need to be adjusted, e.g., `levels = 0:6` if Sunday is coded by a `0`.

Now, plotting the modified data

```
library(ggplot2)  
ggplot(fcast_data1, aes(x = weekday, y = mape_MultExpSmoothFcst)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + #avoid plotting outliers twice
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .1, height = 0)) + 
  # mytheme + 
  ggtitle("May Forecast in May")
```

[image]

`ggplot2`has recognized that the x-axis is a factor and uses a discrete scale instead of a continuous. The factor labels are being used to annotate the breaks. In addition, a separate boxplot is created for each factor level.

Note that the y aesthetic is now referring to `mape_MultExpSmoothFcst` as given in the sample data.

#### Data

The OP has provided sample data in a comment. These have been used here.

```
fcast_data1 <- structure(list(date = c("5/1/2017", "5/1/2017", "5/1/2017", "5/1/2017", 
"5/1/2017", "5/1/2017"), mape_MultExpSmoothFcst = c(39.89361702, 
59.00277008, 42.31678487, 32.20720721, 36.9047619, 26.4033264
), pe_MultExpSmoothFcst = c(39.89361702, 59.00277008, 42.31678487, 
32.20720721, 36.9047619, 26.4033264), weekday = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("date", "mape_MultExpSmoothFcst", "pe_MultExpSmoothFcst", 
"weekday"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Uwe Bloc, thanks for your reply. It worked the way you mentioned. I was missing the "levels = 1:7" while assigning factor to weekdays and it was causing the problem.

Comment: @Manny Thanks for your feedback.